# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to find the minimum value of the column's data without using inbuilt function.

Can anyone please help me on this below issue.

```
import pandas as pd
file_loc= 'filepath'
data= pd.read_csv(file_loc)
cpiData= data['cpi'].unique()
minValue =data['cpi'].head(0)
print("type of min ", type(minValue))
min=100
for i in cpiData:
    print(type(i),"min", minValue.astype(float))
    **if minValue.astype(float) > float(i): # getting the error while comparing both the values.**
        minValue=i

print(min,"Minimum value ")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first correction pertains to the way how to select
the initial value of *minValue*.
Note that your formula (`data['cpi'].head(0)`) actually means:

- `data['cpi']` - take *cpi* column,
- `head(0)` - get **0** initial elements,

so the result is an **empty Series**.

The correct formula is: `minValue = data.iloc[0].cpi`, i.e.:

- `data.iloc[0]` - take the initial row from *data* (it is a *Series*),
- `cpi` - read *cpi* from it.

The rest of your program (a loop, with diagnostic printouts) can
be changed to:

```
for i in cpiData:
    print(i)
    if minValue > i:
        minValue = i
        print('New min')
```

Note that your column is already of *float* type, so you don't
need to convert it to *float*.

And to print the result after the loop, print *minValue*,
not *min* (*min* is a built-in function):

```
print('Minimum value:', minValue)
```

Actually, your instruction `min=100` overwrites  built-in function *min*
with an integer value. Don't do such things, as it destroys your working
environment.

Comment: Sure, I will not use any inbuilt function names for the variables. thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Pandas [`head()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) returns the **first n rows** of your column `data['cpi']`. The type of return value is `pandas.core.series.Series`.

First of all, you may have a bug by returning `head(0)`. It simply returns an empty series.

The [`astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) function changes the type of all elements in the given object to the given `dtype`. Here, the input object is a `Series` (resulting from your call to `head(0)`), so the output object will also be a `Series`, which would contain `float` values.

Now, you are comparing a `Series` (the `minValue.astype(float)`) with a `float` (the `float(i)`), and the error is saying "I don't know how to compare this `Series` object to a `float`", which makes sense.

You can do:

```
minValue[0].astype(float) > float(i)
```

to compare the frist element of Series to `i`. However be ware of the above mentioned potential bug: your series actually does not contain anything, because you are calling `head(0)` instead of `head(1)`.